# How to log [1, 2 ,3] and not [1.0,2.0,3.0] using Logger.log in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to solve a programing puzzle/game.
It's a Spiral Matrix and the result is correct but my array is outputting `.0` at the end of my arrays.

For example, the input is

```json
[1, 2, 3], 
[4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9]
```

The output is

```json
[1.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,4.0,5.0]
```

But I'm looking for

```json
[ 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

The code I am using is from the YouTube video "LeetCode 54 Spiral Matrix in javascript".

How do I `Logger.log(result)` without the `.0`?

```js
function myFunction() {
  matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];
  // result array
  const result = [];
  // boundry varibals
  let left = 0;
  let top = 0;
  let right = matrix[0].length - 1;
  let bottom = matrix.length - 1;
  // starting direction clock wise
  let direction = 'right';
  // start loop
  while (left <= right && top <= bottom) {

    if (direction === 'right') {
      for (let i = left; i <= right; i += 1) {
        result.push(matrix[top][i]);
      }
      top += 1;
      direction = 'down';
    } else if (direction === 'down') {
      for (let i = top; i <= bottom; i += 1) {
        result.push(matrix[i][right]);
      }
      right -= 1;
      direction = 'left';
    } else if (direction === 'left') {
      for (let i = right; i >= left; i -= 1) {
        result.push(matrix[bottom][i]);
      }
      bottom -= 1;
      direction = 'up';
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      for (let i = bottom; i >= top; i -= 1) {
        result.push(matrix[i][left]);

      }

      left += 1;
      direction = 'right';
    }
  }
  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

I'm using [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

Comment: How do you create that output? Because JS behaves exactly opposite to what you describe.

Comment: I am using [Google app script](https://script.google.com/)

Comment: What is `Logger.log`?

Comment: IDK I only know it's how app script outputs a result to the log.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the script I am using.

Comment: Now that you added the bit about google-apps-script I've voted to reopen your question. In the future please include information like that in the original question to avoid misunderstandings: other Javascript environments (e.g. web browser, node.js) do not show the problem you are having, and most Javascript developers (including me!) don't have enough experience using google-apps-script to realize that's what the problem is.

Comment: It seems like that's the number representation of `Logger.log` or the Google log console. You could convert the numbers to strings before logging: `Logger.log(string(result));`

Comment: I am sorry I am new to asking for help as well.

Comment: Instead of adding junk text at the end of your question you could mention Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Dalobie it's fine, that's how you learn. Once somebody (me in this case) votes to reopen a question it goes into a queue for review and as long as a couple of people agree it'll get reopened and hopefully answered. We get a lot of people who dump half-baked questions and then refuse to provide more detail or just disappear, the system usually works for people who stick around and listen to feedback. Also since you added the google-apps-script tag hopefully an expert who subscribes to the tag will see this in their feed and help you out.

Comment: thank you @Jared Smith I have a feeling using a web API as my starting point in programming is going to cause me a few setbacks with my time learning to program

Comment: @Dalobie maybe that specific one, yeah. It probably makes more sense to learn the quirks of a language on a common platform than try to learn the quirks of a language along with the quirks of a more obscure platform at the same time.

Comment: Use `console.log()` as `Logger` has some idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `JSON.stringify()` to your output.

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Output:

[image]

### Reference:

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)